# laravel 7 - add new images on existing tables

Tags: php, laravel

I was successful uploading multiple images while inserting a new record. I used two models `Car` and `caralbum` and made a join. However, I was trying to create an option to add more images on current list but failed to do so. my codes are-

**controller to add new record with multiple images**

```
$car = new Car;
.......
.......
$car->save();
   
if (count($request->car_image) > 0) {
    foreach ($request->car_image as $image) {
        ........
        ........
        Image::make($image)->save($location);

        $caralbum = new caralbum;
        $caralbum->car_id = $car->id;
        $caralbum->image_name = $image_name;
        $caralbum->image_location = $location;
        $caralbum->save();
    }
}
```

**controller to add additional images**

```
$car = Car::find($id);
if (count($request->car_image) > 0) {
    foreach ($request->car_image as $image) {
        ....
        ....
        Image::make($image)->save($location);

        $caralbum = new caralbum;
        $caralbum->car_id = $car->id;
        $caralbum->image_name = $image_name;
        $caralbum->image_location = $location;
        $caralbum->save();
```

**blade to add new record with multiple images**

```
<input type="file" name="car_image[]" multiple>
```

**blade to add additional images**

```
<input type="file" name="car_image[]" multiple>
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ url('car_store_images/'.$cars->id) }}">
    Add Images
</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... it might be better to have a submit button that will submit the form instead of an anchor?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but still getting error: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Answer (score 0):

I have found one problem. on the index blade where I am displaying the images the image class was not named as array. After adding [] after it, it is working now.

```
@foreach ($cars->join_caralbum as $image)
              <div class="card" >
                <img class="card-img-top" name="car_image[]" src="{{asset($image->image_location)}}" style ="height:90px; width:120px;" >
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ url('car_destroy_image/'.$image->id) }}"
                  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete all images for this car?')"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-xs"></i></a>
              </div>
          @endforeach
```